How to organize many small java projects?
We have a rather large overall project which can be subdivided into modules.
For the sake of argument, let us assume we have ~200 modules and each has on average ~200 classes.
Modules are kind of dynamic: New modules may pop up with new requirements and also there may be cases, where modules are no longer needed and therefore discarded.
Initially we thought of organizing this a  multi-module-gradle project. However, the complexity of generating new modules and linking them to one another is not trivial (e.g. we need to prevent circular dependencies among the modules, which has proven quite a hassle).
We therefore considered putting all the modules into packages within one rather large-ish project. Side conditions about dependencies can be checked dynamically via archunit.
However, this new organization will lead to larger build times as javac does not compile in parallel and also gradle seems unable to parallelize the load even when the source files have a natural order and may be compiled independently - the modules have clearly defined interfaces and all modules only reference interfaces and not implementations of other modules.
So the question is:

Is there a way to parallelize the java-build within one large project?
Is there a canonical way how to deal with a project consisting of a large number of dynamically changing sub-modules?


I think one way would be to only use the modules that you really need.  In other words, push some of the complexity into the build script and the check-out script.  If I as a developer can just say "get project X" and I only get and build the files I need, that's better than being required to say "get everything" and then I'm left to figure out what I really need.

Did you enable Gradle parallel builds? https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YQgsRESnjU5nZFhR7btTDaqqcvOYU46y1Rn6IIhsIQg/edit?usp=sharing

Are you using Java Platform Module System in your codebase?

The word “dynamically” is confusing here as that term usually means changing at runtime.

Your Question is too broad, and likely to be closed soon. I suggest you edit to narrowly focus on a particular technical issue, or refine your question to make explicit the specific concerns you have with either approach. A Maven or Gradle multi-module project seems spot-on for your needs. And making your code modular with Java Platform Module System would seem to avoid the inappropriate  dependencies you seem to want to avoid. So I suggest you explain how you see those two technologies fail to address your needs.
